# Easy way to export Graphics3D as triangles with VertexNormals?

Tags: export, graphics3d

I would like to export an arbitrary `Graphics3D` object as a text file containing:

- list of vertices
- vertex normals
- triangle faces

`Export["foo.obj", g]`, `Export["foo.pov", g]`, and `Export["foo.stl", g]` are all unsatisfactory as they lack the `VertexNormal` data.

I started writing my own exporter but it's getting a bit painful as it seems there is no easy way to convert `GraphicsComplex` object containing `Polygon`s of order greater than 3 and converting them to triangles without recreating a triangle tessellation from scratch.

Has anyone done this before and would like to share their code? Or is there an undocumented function I could use?

Here is an example `Graphics3D`:

```
g = RegionPlot3D[(x^2 + y^4 + z^4) - (x^3 + y^2 + z) > 1/2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Have you tried exporting in `X3D`  formats?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site! Perhaps you could provide a minimal working example of your 3d graphics.

Comment: You can't use [NOFF](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/NOFF.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I hadn't tried X3D or NOFF before.

Comment: Dale : NOFF Stores a collection of planar polygons with possibly shared vertices and vertex normal data.

Answer (score 6):

As already stated in the comments, you can surely find a 3d export format which stores the normals too. On the other hand, I believe the only information you are missing is, that there is a function `Normal` (which has nothing to do with the *normals*).

This function transforms a `GraphicsComplex` back to a form where all polygons are stored explicitly. Therefore, you take you `Graphics3D`, apply `Normal` and then you can via e.g. `Cases` and some rules extract all information you like.

OK, let's make this answer worth many upvotes: The triangle faces of your graphics are the first argument in all the `Polygon` calls after you applied `Normal`. The vertices are just in the first argument to `GraphicsComplex`. The normals are supplied as optional argument to `Polygon`.

Using `TagSet` to build a simple access to those information

```
Faces /: gr_Graphics3D.Faces := 
 Cases[Normal[gr], Polygon[__], Infinity] /. Polygon[pts_, ___] :> pts;
Vertices /: gr_Graphics3D.Vertices := 
  gr[[1, 1]] /; gr[[1, 0]] === GraphicsComplex;
Normals /: gr_Graphics3D.Normals := 
 Cases[Normal[gr], Polygon[__], Infinity] /. 
  Polygon[pts_, VertexNormals -> normals_] :> {pts, normals}
```

This should work in basic examples. Please don't try to draw this with a full detailed graphics. Your system may explode.

```
gr = RegionPlot3D[(x^2 + y^4 + z^4) - (x^3 + y^2 + z) > 1/2, {x, -1, 
   1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 5, 
  Mesh -> All];
drawNormals[{pts_, normals_}] := {Arrow[Tube[#, 0.01]] & /@ 
   Transpose[{pts, pts + .5 normals}]};

(* And here comes the simple access: *)
Graphics3D[{Polygon /@ (gr.Faces), Red, drawNormals /@ (gr.Normals), 
  Blue, Sphere[#, 0.05] & /@ (gr.Vertices)}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]