# How to prove or disprove an inequality with Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, inequalities, logic

I mean there exist $\lambda>0, x\in \mathbb R$ s.t. the inequality $$ \frac{3^{\lambda } e^x+e^{3 x}+1}{2^{\lambda } e^{2 x}}<\frac{1}{10^{100}}$$ is valid.

Here are my unsuccessful attempts.

```
Resolve[Exists[\[Lambda], \[Lambda] > 0, Exists[x, (1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/E^(2 x) < 
10^-100]], Reals]
```

returns the input. The same issue with

```
Minimize[{(1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/E^(2 x), \[Lambda] > 0}, {\[Lambda], x}]
```

and

```
FindInstance[(1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/E^(2 x) < 
1/10^100 && \[Lambda] > 0, {\[Lambda], x}, Reals]
```

The result of the command

```
NMinimize[{(1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/E^(2 x), \[Lambda] > 0}, {\[Lambda], x}]
```

> `{0., {\[Lambda] -> 425.496, x -> 236.227}}`

is not any proof because `0.` may be greater than `0`.

Comment: The command `MinLimit[(1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/   E^(2 x), {\[Lambda], x} -> {Infinity, Infinity},   Direction -> "FromBelow"]` results in `-Infinity` which is wrong since the function takes only positive values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to solve equations and impose conditions on parameters (here `fval` ), than to solve inequations.

```
(1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/E^(2 x) < 
   10^-100 /. \[Lambda] -> 1800 /. x -> Log[10^420]

(*   True   *)
```

---

```
f = (1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/E^(2 x);
```

Get rid of the `Exp`

```
sol1 = Flatten@Solve[E^x == ex, x,Reals] // Quiet
```

Transform f < 10^-100 to f == fval  with fval < 10^-100

```
f2 = f - fval /. sol1 // Together // Numerator
```

Get solutions for ex (=E^x) with conditions for fval and lambda

```
sol = Solve[f2 == 0 && ex > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0 && fval < 10^-100, ex, 
       Reals, Method -> Reduce];

sol // N

(*   {{ex -> ConditionalExpression[
Root[1 + 3^\[Lambda] #1 - 2^\[Lambda] fval #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
Root[-27 - 4 3^(3 \[Lambda]) - 
     2^(1 + \[Lambda]) 3^(2 + \[Lambda]) #1 + 
     6^(2 \[Lambda]) #1^2 + 2^(2 + 3 \[Lambda]) #1^3 &, 3] < 
  fval < 1.*10^-100 
&& \[Lambda] > 1605.6]}, 

{ex -> 
  ConditionalExpression[
  Root[1 + 3^\[Lambda] #1 - 2^\[Lambda] fval #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3], 
  Root[-27 - 4 3^(3 \[Lambda]) - 
     2^(1 + \[Lambda]) 3^(2 + \[Lambda]) #1 + 
     6^(2 \[Lambda]) #1^2 + 2^(2 + 3 \[Lambda]) #1^3 &, 3] < 
  fval < 1.*10^-100 
&& \[Lambda] > 1605.6]}}   *)
```

`{{ex -> ConditionalExpression[ Root[1 + 3^\[Lambda] #1 - 2^\[Lambda] fval #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2],  Root[-27 - 4 3^(3 \[Lambda]) -  2^(1 + \[Lambda]) 3^(2 + \[Lambda]) #1 +  6^(2 \[Lambda]) #1^2 + 2^(2 + 3 \[Lambda]) #1^3 &, 3] <  fval < 1.*10^-100 && \[Lambda] > 1605.6]}, {ex ->  ConditionalExpression[ Root[1 + 3^\[Lambda] #1 - 2^\[Lambda] fval #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3],  Root[-27 - 4 3^(3 \[Lambda]) -  2^(1 + \[Lambda]) 3^(2 + \[Lambda]) #1 +  6^(2 \[Lambda]) #1^2 + 2^(2 + 3 \[Lambda]) #1^3 &, 3] <  fval < 1.*10^-100 && \[Lambda] > 1605.6]}}`

Retransform x==Log[ex]

```
(Log[ex] /. sol) /. \[Lambda] -> 2500 /. fval -> 6/10 10^-100 // 
 N[#, 10] &

(*   {1244.432105, 1502.098616}   *)


Reduce[f2 == 0 && ex > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0 && fval < 10^-100, ex,         Reals]//N
```

`\[Lambda] >  1605.6 && ((fval ==  Root[-27 - 4 3^(3 \[Lambda]) -  2^(1 + \[Lambda]) 3^(2 + \[Lambda]) #1 +  6^(2 \[Lambda]) #1^2 + 2^(2 + 3 \[Lambda]) #1^3 &, 3] &&  ex == Root[1 + 3^\[Lambda] #1 - 2^\[Lambda] fval #1^2 + #1^3 &,  2]) || (Root[-27 - 4 3^(3 \[Lambda]) -  2^(1 + \[Lambda]) 3^(2 + \[Lambda]) #1 +  6^(2 \[Lambda]) #1^2 + 2^(2 + 3 \[Lambda]) #1^3 &, 3] <  fval < 1.*10^-100 && (ex ==  Root[1 + 3^\[Lambda] #1 - 2^\[Lambda] fval #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2] || ex == Root[ 1 + 3^\[Lambda] #1 - 2^\[Lambda] fval #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3])))`

Edit made by @user6494. For the user's convenience (In order not to read the below comments.), I fixed the omitted `Reals` in  `sol1 = Flatten@Solve[E^x == ex, x,Reals] // Quiet`.

In version my version 8.0 Reals is not neccessary. (Akku14)

Comment: Thank you. I will be waiting for a systematic solution produced by Mathematica.

Comment: Ehank you for your edit. 1. Unfortunately, your code is not commented. 2. `sol = Solve[f2 == 0 && ex > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0 && fval < 10^-100, ex, 
  Reals, Method -> Reduce]` returns the input

Comment: `Solve[ConditionalExpression[-((
     2^-\[Lambda] E^(-4 I \[Pi] ConditionalExpression[
        1, \[Placeholder]]) (-1 - 
        3^\[Lambda] E^(
         2 I \[Pi] ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]]) ex - 
        E^(6 I \[Pi] ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]]) ex^3 + 
        2^\[Lambda] E^(
         4 I \[Pi] ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]])
          ex^2 fval))/ex^2) == 0 && ex > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0 && 
   fval < 1/
     100000000000....
000000000000000000000000000000000000, 
  ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]] \[Element] Integers]` for me.

Comment: Works fine in version 8.0

Comment: Akku14 (@ does not work.): Can you present the executed *.nb file and/or its PDF export through Dropbox?

Comment: Made some explanations. Try it with Reduce.

Comment: `sol = Reduce[f2 == 0 && ex > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0 && fval < 10^-100, ex, 
       Reals]` also returns the input and a message "The system Subscript[\[ConstantC], \
1]\[Element]\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]&&-((2^-\[Lambda] <<1>> (-1-3^\
\[Lambda] E^<<1>> ex-E^<<1>> <<1>>+2^\[Lambda] E^(4 I \[Pi] \
Subscript[\[ConstantC], <<1>>]) ex^2 \
fval))/ex^2)==0&&ex>0&&\[Lambda]>0&&fval<1/\
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
00000...00000 contains a nonreal constant -4 I. \
With the domain \[DoubleStruckCapitalR] specified, all constants \
should be real".

Comment: Your code works with `sol1 = Flatten@Solve[E^x == ex, x, Reals]` instead of `sol1 = Flatten@Solve[E^x == ex, x]`. However, then `sol = Reduce[f2 == 0 && ex > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0 && fval < 10^-100, ex,
   Reals]//N` produces

Comment: `\[Lambda] > 
  1605.6 && ((fval == 
      Root[-27 - 4 3^(3 \[Lambda]) - 
         2^(1 + \[Lambda]) 3^(2 + \[Lambda]) #1 + 
         6^(2 \[Lambda]) #1^2 + 2^(2 + 3 \[Lambda]) #1^3 &, 3] && 
     ex == Root[1 + 3^\[Lambda] #1 - 2^\[Lambda] fval #1^2 + #1^3 &, 
       2]) || (Root[-27 - 4 3^(3 \[Lambda]) - 
         2^(1 + \[Lambda]) 3^(2 + \[Lambda]) #1 + 
         6^(2 \[Lambda]) #1^2 + 2^(2 + 3 \[Lambda]) #1^3 &, 3] < 
      fval < 1.*10^-100 && (ex == 
        Root[1 + 3^\[Lambda] #1 - 2^\[Lambda] fval #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2] ||
     `

Comment: `ex == Root[
         1 + 3^\[Lambda] #1 - 2^\[Lambda] fval #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3])))` without any `ConditionalExpression`.

Comment: Your Result for Reduce ... is exactly the same as  i get, if i apply  additional //N. Thats the right result. You may apply Solve on that result. Of course, Reduce yields no ConditionalExpression, only Solve does.

Comment: For the user's convenience, can you kindly fix the issue with `Reals` in your good answer? TIA.

Comment: I find this answer more or less completely describing the solutions, so I accept it.

Comment: I am sure most of users don't use version 8.

Answer (score 2):

`RegionPlot` shows  the possible solution space.

Assuming `((1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/E^(2 x))>0` (shown by OP):

```
eps = 10 ^-100;
gr=RegionPlot[Log[((1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/E^(2 x))] < 
Log[eps], {\[Lambda], 0, 2500}, { x, 0, 2500 } , 
PlotPoints -> 500, FrameLabel -> {"\[Lambda]", " x "},MaxRecursion -> 5] // Quiet
```

[image]

`gr[[1,1]][[1]] (*{{1613.23, 886.774}, {1618.24, 886.774}, {1623.25, 891.784},...}*)` gives a lengthy list of solutionpoints.

Comment: Thank you. Can you extract and indicate some values of `\[Lambda]` and `x` validating the inequality from the above plot? It works without  `Quiet` for me in 13 on Windows 10.

Comment: @user64494 Added to my answer

Comment: Thank you for your edit. 1. Can you comment your `gr[[1,1]][[1]]`  to be understandable for an average user? 2. Executing `(1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/E^(2 x) <    10^-100 /. {\[Lambda] -> 1613.2264514500012,    x -> 886.7735485500076}`, I obtain a warning "General::munfl: Exp[-1773.55] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost. ", not only `True`, so this `True` is doubtful.

Comment: `gr[[1,1]][[1]] ` gives the list of points used  in the GraphiComplex `gr`. Have a look inside `gr` witth `??gr` . The condition includes numbers `O[10^-100] `, you should adapt Workingprecision to get trusting "True".

Comment: Thank you. 1. Is "`gr[[1,1]][[1]]`  gives the list of points used in the GraphiComplex gr. " described in the documentation? If so, can you give a reference ?. 2. How to adapt `WorkingPrecision` in `(1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/E^(2 x) <    10^-100 /. {\[Lambda] -> 1613.2264514500012,    x -> 886.7735485500076}`?

Comment: Try `(1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/E^(2 x) < 10^-100 /. 
 Rationalize[{\[Lambda] -> 1613.2264514500012 , 
   x -> 886.7735485500076}, 0]`

Comment: Thank you. Works.  However, `gr[[1,1]][[1]]` is still not explained according to the documentation.

Comment: I don't think that I have to lead you through documentation! Lookup info  `GraphicsComplex`  as proposed by me some comments ago.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any explanation [there](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html). Your `gr[[1,1]][[1]] ` seems to be undocumented.

Comment: Perhaps [halirutan's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11688/easy-way-to-export-graphics3d-as-triangles-with-vertexnormals) helps

Comment: I don't think so. 1. That was about `Graphics3D`. 2. The result of `gr` is not a polygon. What are vertices of `gr`?

Comment: One more remark. In any case, so-called vertices belong to the boundary of the   region defined by the strict inequality under consideration. Therefore, their coordinates may not satisfy the inequality.

Comment: @user64494  Am yet again and again amazed: While you are asking for information you simultanously   claim remarks, which aren't true. #1 Mathematica `vertices ` are all points of a Graphics object. #2 Of course `gr` contains  polygons.

Comment: 1. Is your statement " Mathematica vertices are all points of a Graphics object" true? Let us consider an example from the documentation: `g = GraphicsComplex[{{0, 0}, {Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3]/2}}, {Point[1],      Line[{1, 2}]}];g[[1, 1]][[1]]` which results in`0`, but `Graphics[g]` shows more than this. 2. Please, be correct in your conversation. –

Comment: Without enclosing `Graphics` you get the points with `g[[1,1]]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my tricky answer. First, the result of

```
Limit[(1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/E^(2 x) /. 
x -> Log[3]/2*\[Lambda], \[Lambda] -> Infinity]
```

> `0`

guarantees the existence of the required solution.
Second,

```
NSolve[Expand[(1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/E^(2 x) /. 
 x -> Log[3]/2*\[Lambda]] == 1/2*10^-100 && \[Lambda] >= 0 && \[Lambda] <= 3000 , \[Lambda]]
```

> `{{\[Lambda] -> 1610.42}}`

finds a one solution of the inequality under consideration.

Addition. A simple approach which uses `NMinimize` is as follows.

```
NMinimize[{1, (1 + 3^\[Lambda]*E^x + E^(3 x))/2^\[Lambda]/E^(2 x) < 
10^-100 && x^2 + \[Lambda]^2 >= 2*10^6 && 
x^2 + \[Lambda]^2 <= 10^7}, {x, \[Lambda]}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 100, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> `{1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,{x->1792.682158676924591695765318215658904932218868106718701333477115390170263646455485621517086104184032,\[Lambda]->2605.050993351464904744268828659450449353575490756371168671954922778805769014234476770620073231372436}}`

Comment: One may take a somewhat greater or smaller number than `Log[3]/2`.